# could anyone help me to write a code to this question?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

An HR system has an Employee table that holds a row for each employee within the company. Each record in the table has a employee id, employee name and manager column,  that holds the id for the employee's manager. Write a trigger so that when an employee  record is deleted, the record details need to be inserted into an table called Employee_archive along with the deleted date.

```
EMPLOYEE:
EMPID         NUMBER    PRIMARY KEY
EMPNAME       VARCHAR2(25)   
MANAGERID     NUMBER     

EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE:
EMPID         NUMBER    PRIMARY KEY
EMPNAME       VARCHAR2(25)   
MANAGERID     NUMBER     
DELETED_DATE  DATE
```

(Hint: Data is case sensitive. Use '/' to terminate the PLSQL block)

Comment: Hello, you should read about how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be pretty simple:

```
create or replace trigger trg_bd_emp
  before delete on employee
  for each row
begin
  insert into employee_archive (empid, empname, managerid, deleted_date)
    values (:old.empid, :old.empname, :old.managerid, sysdate);
end trg_bd_emp;
/
```

Though, what is that *hint* supposed to mean? What does letter case have to do with the problem?